# excel 2003 vb writing class

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a class like in java/C# in excel 2003 using visual basic. But I do not know where to write that class.

Is this an example of writing class? If yes where should I put these in excel 2003?

```
Type Employee
    Name As String
    Address As String
    Salary As Double
End Type
```

Comment: Excel 2003... well, it's 2013 now. How about launching Visual Basic Editor by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have there is a User Defined Type (a fixed data structure) which you can place in any module in your project.

To create a class module (which I presume is what you're looking for), right click the VBA project -> Insert -> Class Module

[image]